# How to automate the download and installation of Sitecore update packages generated from TFS build?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, sitecore, azure-devops, sitecore7

I am developing a Sitecore solution locally using TDS. Our source control and build server is Visual Studio Team Services (in the cloud).  I would like to figure out a way to implement Continuous Integration and get builds to be automatically installed on an Integration server that is an Amazon VM (or it could be some other externally located server). I have the TDS build configuration set up to create a Sitecore Update Package.  The build process works great.  At the end of the build process I have the Sitecore Update Package sitting in a Drops folder in source control (TFS in the cloud).  Now I can't figure out how to automate the process of getting that update package out of source control and downloading it to the Integration server and running the Sitecore command to install it.

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect world you would use something along the lines of a fancy Microsoft Release Management to deploy it to the environment of choice. However, if you are like the majority of us mere mortals without the fancy tools - this should help: https://github.com/adoprog/Sitecore-Deployment-Helpers

With these pages you could just send a get request from TFS or use the logic to write a custom PowerShell post-build script. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That will definitely come in handy once I get the generated packages downloaded on to the Integration server.  But I can't figure out how to automate the download of the generated packages to the Integration server from TFS.  Remember, I kick off a build automatically after checking in code.  The build happens in the cloud.  The generated Sitecore packages are sitting in TFS in the cloud.  How can I then get some other server (our Integration server) to download those files automatically?  Then after that I can use the deployment helpers to install.

Comment: I guess I am hoping that there is some "normal" way when you are using TFS in the cloud to automate the process of getting your builds either pushed or downloaded to some Integration or QA server somewhere.  The only solutions I have found involve a ton of custom coding.  Maybe TFS in the cloud expects that you are using Azure for your Integration and QA sites.

Comment: hmmm...without custom coding the solution off the top of my head i can only think of possibly leveraging Web Deploy to copy the package over; possibly having a post-build script with a line calling it to copy the generated package to another location.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using TFS you get to use Release Management for Visual Studio out of the box. This is a simple install but at this time is separate. I have an instance of RM running in a VM and attached to my VSO instance for running deployments.

I would expect this tool, which was bought by MS last year, would become more integrated in vNext.